# ASP.NET Core default template project fails with HTTP ERROR 404 or Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have a problem with ASP.NET Core MVC or Razor `applaunch.json`.

I use a default template to create a project with default settings:

- ASP.Net Core Web App - Dot Net 6
- ASP.Net Core Web App MVC - Dot Net 6

This is my `applaunch.json`:

```
{
    "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": false,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iisExpress": {
            "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:18583",
            "sslPort": 44326
        }
    },
    "profiles": {
        "WebApplication12": {
            "commandName": "Project",
            "dotnetRunMessages": true,
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7081;http://localhost:5081",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        },
        "IIS Express": {
            "commandName": "IISExpress",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And program.cs :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

After launch console shows that no problem with listening to ports :

[image: Console after launch]

But I get an exception for my ASP.NET Core MVC projects:

[image: When running MVC projects]

And I get 404 for Razor Pages:

[image: When running Razor Page projects]

All configurations are default template configurations.

Did anyone experience the same problem?

Comment: **launch** - not "lunch" .....

Comment: In the same directory of the project, do `dotnet run watch` and see if that helps. I had a similar problem and the root cause might be Visual Studio did not attempt or its launch of  `dotnet run` got killed.

Comment: @devyJava It's working with `dotnet run watch` but launching with Visual Studio not working and it's really annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` package and adding the following service:

For ASP.NET Core Razor template

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

And for the MVC project template:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

The second solution is to use `dotnet run watch` either in Developer Power Shell or Command-Line.

Comment: This solved my problem also, adding the `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()` to `AddControllersWithView()`. Trying to fully understand why it worked though

Comment: @Isaac Yes it works, yet I could not manage to understand what is going on under the hood; please share if you find something :)

Comment: Solved my problem too. But I have no idea why the default template is not working by default.